# Unity: most efficient way to have vegetation/field of grass (mobile performance)?

Tags: c#, ios, performance, unity-game-engine, game-engine

Ok, I know the easiest way to make (pretty high poly) grass in Unity 3d is just randomly spawn some grass prefabs across an area -  I need my grass/vegetation to grow like this: https://dribbble.com/shots/4726918-Time-lapse-Air-Plant

But, with lots of polys and, as this was created using an armature (bones drag on performance as well), I need to find the MOST EFFICIENT way to make a forest of growing vegetation without lowering the FPS. I'm targeting iOS/Android, and already seeing low FPS on high poly count models.

Keeping in mind that each blade/vegetation needs to animate to grow (ideally these would all be randomly varied somehow) - what is best for mobile performance? Would spawning randomly even with each model having an armature not cause a problem?

What's the common route here?

Comment: Normally grass are billboard textures (that means they rotate to face the camera) https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/terrain-Grass.html . But looking at the image you just showed that doesn't look like a high poly count model IF its optimized for a game engine (normal/height maps for example)

Comment: @AdrianSgro Ok.. So using this kind of model, if optimized, I could just spawn say 1000 with armatures without affecting performance?

Comment: As a wild estimate, a model of that caliber looks like a 1k tris model top. 1 millon tris for grass in an android app is pretty darn expensive. Then as you said you have the armature of everyone. The thing with armatures is with longer number of bones, the longer the processing time. I don't think you can do something like that for android. Even in PC/consoles it wouldn't be worth it.

Comment: I forgot to add, all this applies if you want the 1000 animations/models on the camera at the same time. If not, you ca use several optimization techniques to reduce the burden on the CPU/GPU https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MecanimPeformanceandOptimization.html

Comment: Ok.. So provided I would want a whole field of grass at the same time what would you suggest to achieve this? What do pro devs do for this?